# Reduce database size (mysqldump) before restoring

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 42Gb mysqldump of my database (which is like 100gb). I have searched over the web if there is any way of reducing the disk size of the database, I mean, once the dump is restored, I want the disk size to reduce from 100gb to 87-90Gb of space. I haven't found any relevant information yet.

I would appreciatte if anyone could guide me a little bit about this.

Thanks

Comment: If it's large due to InnoDB .ibd files, it may take less space on disk already after restoring it. Those files grow with inserts but like disk fragmentation, do not shrink with deletes. Recreating the tables via reloading them from dumps optimizes them.

Comment: There are many ways to do that. From deleting (old) records and logs, different kind compression. different method of datastorage, etc. Be specific what you want and why.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is the problem? Sometimes a 100 gb database need 100 gb space, and just because you want it to be 90 gb isn't going to happen. Like I want date Gisele Bündchen but isn't going to happen any time soon. (damm you Tom Brady)

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the CREATE TABLE statements so they create compressed tables as they restore:

```
sed -e 's/ENGINE=InnoDB/& ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED/' dump.sql | mysql ...
```

Another idea is to drop some or all of the indexes in large tables before restoring data. Insert `ALTER TABLE <tablename> DROP KEY <indexname>;` statements after the CREATE TABLE and before the subsequent INSERT statements.

Even if you decide later that you want the indexes after all, creating the index after data has been loaded often results in a more compact index.

Removing indexes might impact the performance of some of your queries that need those indexes. But if it's more important to make the database smaller, then it's up to you how much you sacrifice query performance.

I'll leave it to you to figure out how you want to edit a 42GB file. Different solutions exist depending on your environment (Mac, Windows, Linux).